# How to remote provision FreeRADIUS server?

Tags: rest, freeradius

I need to add users to a FreeRADIUS server (exactly: to it‘s radcheck database table) from another system.

The other system can call a REST API, but is unable to connect directly to the FreeRADIUS database.

Is there any standard API available for FreeRADIUS?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you have a simple problem here. You need to manipulate a remote database.

Since FreeRADIUS isn't geared to accept requests outside of the specification, you'll have to construct a standalone API on that server that provides DB manipulation endpoints. That way you can hit the endpoint with your new radcheck info and update the DB. One idea.

FreeRADIUS will react as directed after the DB update.
FreeRADIUS doesn't hold dominance over the DB, and only your configuration dictates where it gets its information from.

So you can change that source outside of FreeRADIUS as you please.